# How to avoid default construction of elements in thrust::device_vector?

Tags: c, cuda, gpgpu, thrust

1. It seems when creating a new Thrust vector **all elements are 0 by default** - I just want to confirm that this will always be the case.
2. If so, is there also a way to **bypass the constructor** responsible for this behavior for additional speed (since for some vectors I don't need them to have an initial value, e.g. if their raw pointers are being passed to CUBLAS as an output)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`thrust::device_vector` constructs the elements it contains using its supplied allocator, just like `std::vector`. It's possible to control what the allocator does when the vector asks it to construct an element.

Use a custom allocator to avoid default-initialization of vector elements:

```
// uninitialized_allocator is an allocator which
// derives from device_allocator and which has a
// no-op construct member function
template<typename T>
  struct uninitialized_allocator
    : thrust::device_malloc_allocator<T>
{
  // note that construct is annotated as
  // a __host__ __device__ function
  __host__ __device__
  void construct(T *p)
  {
    // no-op
  }
};

// to make a device_vector which does not initialize its elements,
// use uninitialized_allocator as the 2nd template parameter
typedef thrust::device_vector<float, uninitialized_allocator<float> > uninitialized_vector;
```

You will still incur the cost of a kernel launch to invoke `uninitialized_allocator::construct`, but that kernel will be a no-op which will retire quickly. What you're really interested in is avoiding the memory bandwidth required to fill the array, which this solution does.

There's a complete example code [here](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/uninitialized_vector.cu).

Note that this technique requires Thrust 1.7 or better.

Comment: Very nice.  Despite having written debug allocator overloads for stl before, I forgot the final construct call was here.  Should have kept digging.  +1 :)

Comment: Actually -- I'm confused.  Am I wrong in that the `resize` in your example chains to `insert`, which in turn chains to `fill_insert`, which ends up in `uninitialized_fill_n` again?  So you're still getting copies, despite possibly ignoring the `construct` when setting up the new `storage_type` area there?  ...obviously I need to go step through this in a debugger, but I'm not seeing how the eventual `uninitialized_fill_n` from the default/value initialized `x` default arg can be avoided.

Comment: You may need to step through in a debugger with the most recent Thrust. It's a complicated dispatch.

Comment: Got it, sorry.  For some reason I was simply missing the one-arg version of resize() in vector_base.inl.  Sorry for the bother!  For anyone watching along, the stack is: (1) detail::contiguous_storage::contiguous_storage(unsigned int n, const uninitialized_allocator<float> & alloc) (2) detail::vector_base::append(unsigned int n) (3) detail::vector_base::resize(unsigned int new_size)